# Клиент для сайта на Qt

Tags: qt, api, qtcreator, fileupload, client

Мне нужно разработать desktop клиент для моего личного сайта. У сайта на всякий случай прикручено API.

Назначение клиента следующее - авторизоваться через клиент на сайте, далее загружать фотографии через клиент на сайт.

Хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы например если работаешь через клиент, в заголовках было какое-нибудь дополнительное поле, например `X_Qt_Client` - это нужно для того, чтобы скрипт на php мог понять грузили фотографии с сайта или через клиент.

Есть ли где что-нибудь подобное? или хотя бы в какую сторону копать?

Cайт на php, ответ API-JSON.

Comment: а почeму именно QT? думаю что например вариант как Electron (если норм разбираешься в вебе) был бы тоже не плох.

Comment: Ну просто читал, что чаще используют в разработке, посоветовали Qt.

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setRawHeader

Comment: Спасибо. Но это только по заголовкам.

Comment: так что, дать ссылки на функцию post? QNetworkAccessManager поможет сделать все сетевую часть. А остальное - это уже Ваша фантазия.

Comment: Он поможет с авторизацией?